# two applications opening a single file at the same time

Tags: c, memory, fopen

I have two programs which are opening the same file in "w" mode. The file pointers returned are same in both cases. I understood that this should not happen. Am i wrong?

Comment: Do not understand what you mean by : "The file pointers returned are same in both cases". And you should look up "race condition". You could run in to big issues when the same space is written to from multiple threads/applications/.. at the same time

Comment: what happens if both the programs try to write to the same file at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

That simultaneously opening a file for writing could lead to bad race conditions and synchronization problems was already mentioned.

To your question:  `fopen` returns an pointer to a `FILE` structure. This structure is allocated in the private memory space of the application. Nowadays, each process has its own independent [(virtual) memory address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) space (mapped by the operating system to real memory addresses). So if the same memory address  is used in two independent programs, normally the real memory behind is not the same.

In the FILE structure there is a (integer) file handle which is provided by the operating system to identify the file, but file handles are (at least in Unix like systems) application specific, so even if they are equal, this means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage concurrency. If 2 different programs or threads access a single resource, they need to be managed for them to access the resource (in this case the file) with a mutually exclusive condition.